# SVG logo in Bootstrap's navbar-brand

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg

### Explanation

I'm trying to place my `SVG` logo in a Bootstrap's navbar, but, for some reason, it won't work. I've tried to use `<object>` (as recommended at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-11)), inline svg and `<img>`, as you can see in the code below, but nothing worked.

### Code

You can save the `SVG` logo to use with `<object>` from [Bootstrap's site](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/about/brand/#download-mark) or [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/96tupjy36iu7jxm/logo.svg?dl=0).

```css
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(72, 8, 111, 0.4);
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Page Title -->
        <title>svg on bootstrap's navbar</title>

 <!-- CSS
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>

    <body id="body">

        <header id="navigation" class="navbar-fixed-top navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- responsive nav button -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
             <!-- end responsive nav button -->


      <!-- logo png -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qHjO7J9.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <!-- end logo png -->

                    <!-- logo object
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                       <object type="image/svg+xml" data="logo.svg" class="logo">
                           Logo
                       </object>
                    </a>
                     end logo object -->

                    <!-- logo inline svg
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" enable-background="new 0 0 612 612" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="solid" sodipodi:docname="twitter_bootstrap_logo.svg" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"><path id="bg" fill="#563D7C" d="M612 510c0 56.1-45.9 102-102 102H102C45.9 612 0 566.1 0 510V102C0 45.9 45.9 0 102 0h408c56.1 0 102 45.9 102 102V510z"/><g id="B" enable-background="new    "><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M166.3 133h173.5c32 0 57.7 7.3 77 22s29 36.8 29 66.5c0 18-4.4 33.4-13.2 46.2 -8.8 12.8-21.4 22.8-37.8 29.8v1c22 4.7 38.7 15.1 50 31.2 11.3 16.2 17 36.4 17 60.8 0 14-2.5 27.1-7.5 39.2 -5 12.2-12.8 22.7-23.5 31.5s-24.3 15.8-41 21 -36.5 7.8-59.5 7.8h-164L166.3 133 166.3 133zM228.8 282.5h102c15 0 27.5-4.2 37.5-12.8s15-20.8 15-36.8c0-18-4.5-30.7-13.5-38s-22-11-39-11h-102L228.8 282.5 228.8 282.5zM228.8 439h110.5c19 0 33.8-4.9 44.2-14.8 10.5-9.8 15.8-23.8 15.8-41.8 0-17.7-5.2-31.2-15.8-40.8s-25.2-14.2-44.2-14.2H228.8V439z"/></g></g></svg>
      </a>
       end logo inline svg -->

                    <!-- logo img svg
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                        <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                     end logo img svg -->

                </div>

         <!-- main nav -->
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#First">First</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Second">Second</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Third">Third</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Forth">Forth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
  <!-- end main nav -->

            </div>
        </header>


        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" enable-background="new 0 0 612 612" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="solid" sodipodi:docname="twitter_bootstrap_logo.svg" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"><path id="bg" fill="#563D7C" d="M612 510c0 56.1-45.9 102-102 102H102C45.9 612 0 566.1 0 510V102C0 45.9 45.9 0 102 0h408c56.1 0 102 45.9 102 102V510z"/><g id="B" enable-background="new    "><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M166.3 133h173.5c32 0 57.7 7.3 77 22s29 36.8 29 66.5c0 18-4.4 33.4-13.2 46.2 -8.8 12.8-21.4 22.8-37.8 29.8v1c22 4.7 38.7 15.1 50 31.2 11.3 16.2 17 36.4 17 60.8 0 14-2.5 27.1-7.5 39.2 -5 12.2-12.8 22.7-23.5 31.5s-24.3 15.8-41 21 -36.5 7.8-59.5 7.8h-164L166.3 133 166.3 133zM228.8 282.5h102c15 0 27.5-4.2 37.5-12.8s15-20.8 15-36.8c0-18-4.5-30.7-13.5-38s-22-11-39-11h-102L228.8 282.5 228.8 282.5zM228.8 439h110.5c19 0 33.8-4.9 44.2-14.8 10.5-9.8 15.8-23.8 15.8-41.8 0-17.7-5.2-31.2-15.8-40.8s-25.2-14.2-44.2-14.2H228.8V439z"/></g></g></svg>
            </div>
        </section>


 <!-- jQuery Plugins
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see below the  tag works, as far as the placement in the html goes. I did have to add some css for sizing. I had to use just some random svg I found to demo it. Where is "logo.svg" being served from in your example?

```css
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(72, 8, 111, 0.4);
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Page Title -->
        <title>svg on bootstrap's navbar</title>

 <!-- CSS
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>

    <body id="body">

        <header id="navigation" class="navbar-fixed-top navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- responsive nav button -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
             <!-- end responsive nav button -->


      <!-- logo png -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qHjO7J9.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <!-- end logo png -->

                    <!-- logo object
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                       <object type="image/svg+xml" data="logo.svg" class="logo">
                           Logo
                       </object>
                    </a>
                     end logo object -->

                    <!-- logo inline svg
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" enable-background="new 0 0 612 612" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="solid" sodipodi:docname="twitter_bootstrap_logo.svg" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"><path id="bg" fill="#563D7C" d="M612 510c0 56.1-45.9 102-102 102H102C45.9 612 0 566.1 0 510V102C0 45.9 45.9 0 102 0h408c56.1 0 102 45.9 102 102V510z"/><g id="B" enable-background="new    "><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M166.3 133h173.5c32 0 57.7 7.3 77 22s29 36.8 29 66.5c0 18-4.4 33.4-13.2 46.2 -8.8 12.8-21.4 22.8-37.8 29.8v1c22 4.7 38.7 15.1 50 31.2 11.3 16.2 17 36.4 17 60.8 0 14-2.5 27.1-7.5 39.2 -5 12.2-12.8 22.7-23.5 31.5s-24.3 15.8-41 21 -36.5 7.8-59.5 7.8h-164L166.3 133 166.3 133zM228.8 282.5h102c15 0 27.5-4.2 37.5-12.8s15-20.8 15-36.8c0-18-4.5-30.7-13.5-38s-22-11-39-11h-102L228.8 282.5 228.8 282.5zM228.8 439h110.5c19 0 33.8-4.9 44.2-14.8 10.5-9.8 15.8-23.8 15.8-41.8 0-17.7-5.2-31.2-15.8-40.8s-25.2-14.2-44.2-14.2H228.8V439z"/></g></g></svg>
      </a>
       end logo inline svg -->

                    <!-- logo img svg-->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
                        <img style="max-height: 30px;" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
                        <!--img src="" alt="logo"-->
                    </a>
                     <!--end logo img svg -->

                </div>

         <!-- main nav -->
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#First">First</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Second">Second</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Third">Third</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Forth">Forth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
  <!-- end main nav -->

            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- REMOVE THIS
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" enable-background="new 0 0 612 612" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="solid" sodipodi:docname="twitter_bootstrap_logo.svg" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"><path id="bg" fill="#563D7C" d="M612 510c0 56.1-45.9 102-102 102H102C45.9 612 0 566.1 0 510V102C0 45.9 45.9 0 102 0h408c56.1 0 102 45.9 102 102V510z"/><g id="B" enable-background="new    "><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M166.3 133h173.5c32 0 57.7 7.3 77 22s29 36.8 29 66.5c0 18-4.4 33.4-13.2 46.2 -8.8 12.8-21.4 22.8-37.8 29.8v1c22 4.7 38.7 15.1 50 31.2 11.3 16.2 17 36.4 17 60.8 0 14-2.5 27.1-7.5 39.2 -5 12.2-12.8 22.7-23.5 31.5s-24.3 15.8-41 21 -36.5 7.8-59.5 7.8h-164L166.3 133 166.3 133zM228.8 282.5h102c15 0 27.5-4.2 37.5-12.8s15-20.8 15-36.8c0-18-4.5-30.7-13.5-38s-22-11-39-11h-102L228.8 282.5 228.8 282.5zM228.8 439h110.5c19 0 33.8-4.9 44.2-14.8 10.5-9.8 15.8-23.8 15.8-41.8 0-17.7-5.2-31.2-15.8-40.8s-25.2-14.2-44.2-14.2H228.8V439z"/></g></g></svg>
            </div>
        </section>
        -->

 <!-- jQuery Plugins
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

You main problem is that you haven't specified a size for the SVG.  If the SVG doesn't have `width` or `height` attributes, they default to "100%" - that is 100% width (of the parent container).

Below I have just set the width in the CSS and it is now a more reasonable size.  You will want to add more styling to get it to sit where you want in the header bar.

```css
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(72, 8, 111, 0.4);
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Page Title -->
        <title>svg on bootstrap's navbar</title>

 <!-- CSS
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>

    <body id="body">

        <header id="navigation" class="navbar-fixed-top navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- responsive nav button -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
             <!-- end responsive nav button -->


      <!-- logo png -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#First">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qHjO7J9.png" alt="logo">
      </a>

                </div>

         <!-- main nav -->
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#First">First</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Second">Second</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Third">Third</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Forth">Forth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
  <!-- end main nav -->

            </div>
        </header>


        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" enable-background="new 0 0 612 612" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" id="solid" sodipodi:docname="twitter_bootstrap_logo.svg" inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"><path id="bg" fill="#563D7C" d="M612 510c0 56.1-45.9 102-102 102H102C45.9 612 0 566.1 0 510V102C0 45.9 45.9 0 102 0h408c56.1 0 102 45.9 102 102V510z"/><g id="B" enable-background="new    "><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M166.3 133h173.5c32 0 57.7 7.3 77 22s29 36.8 29 66.5c0 18-4.4 33.4-13.2 46.2 -8.8 12.8-21.4 22.8-37.8 29.8v1c22 4.7 38.7 15.1 50 31.2 11.3 16.2 17 36.4 17 60.8 0 14-2.5 27.1-7.5 39.2 -5 12.2-12.8 22.7-23.5 31.5s-24.3 15.8-41 21 -36.5 7.8-59.5 7.8h-164L166.3 133 166.3 133zM228.8 282.5h102c15 0 27.5-4.2 37.5-12.8s15-20.8 15-36.8c0-18-4.5-30.7-13.5-38s-22-11-39-11h-102L228.8 282.5 228.8 282.5zM228.8 439h110.5c19 0 33.8-4.9 44.2-14.8 10.5-9.8 15.8-23.8 15.8-41.8 0-17.7-5.2-31.2-15.8-40.8s-25.2-14.2-44.2-14.2H228.8V439z"/></g></g></svg>
            </div>
        </section>


 <!-- jQuery Plugins
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked just great, but as I can only set one answer to this question, I'm setting the other one, because it was answered before. By the way, your answer is just as good as the first one.